# Creating ASP.Net Core IAuthorizationRequirement that is based on route parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I have groups of pages that share common authorization requirements. Consider the following structure:

```
https://example.com/Company/{companyId}/Billing/Index
https://example.com/Company/{companyId}/Billing/Edit
https://example.com/Company/{companyId}/Billing/(other pages)
https://example.com/Company/{companyId}/Profile/Index
https://example.com/Company/{companyId}/Profile/Edit
https://example.com/Company/{companyId}/Profile/(other pages)
```

I need to ensure that users getting to any pages under `/Company/{companyId}/Billing` have authorization to manage billing within the company with `id = {companyId}`. Likewise, users requesting pages underneath `/Company/{companyId}/Profile` must have authorization to manage profile information for the company included in the route. It is not a simple role ... it is a role as applied to a company, which configuration is in our database.

I have a solution that is working, but it just seems ... wrong. I'm having to sniff for the `{companyId}` route id within the `AuthorizationHandler`, and that just doesn't seem right. Surely this must be a common enough scenario (protecting resources not just based on role, but based on the details of the actual resource) that there's a smoother way.

I am including my current solution as an answer below, but welcome feedback and recommendations for a better implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my current solution, but it just doesn't seem like this is "the right way". In particular, it seems to me like the company id should somehow be part of the `CompanyAuthorizationRequirement`, and not something being sniffed in the authorization handler.

Create an `IAuthorizationRequirement` with which to mark the resources that need to be protected:

```
public class CompanyAuthorizationRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public CompanyAuthorizationRequirement(string permission)
    {
        this.Permission = permission;
    }

    public string Permission { get; private set; }
}
```

Create an `AuthorizationHandler` to handle the requirement:

```
public class CompanyAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CompanyAuthorizationRequirement>
{
    private readonly IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor;
    private readonly IAuthorizationRepository authorizationRepository;

    public CompanyAuthorizationHandler(IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor, IAuthorizationRepository authorizationRepository)
    {
        this.actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
        this.authorizationRepository = authorizationRepository;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CompanyAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.IsInRole(RoleNames.SystemAdministrator))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return;
        }

        // This is the part that smells wrong to me...
        object companyIdRouteData = this.actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["companyId"];
        if (companyIdRouteData == null)
        {
            companyIdRouteData = this.actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["companyId"];
        }

        if (companyIdRouteData == null || !int.TryParse(companyIdRouteData.ToString(), out int companyId))
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }

        string userId = context.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;
        bool authorized = false;

        switch (requirement.Permission)
        {
            case "billing":
                authorized = await this.authorizationRepository.CanManageCompanyBilling(userId, companyId);
                break;

            case "profile":
                authorized = await this.authorizationRepository.CanManageCompanyProfile(userId, companyId);
                break;
        }

        if (authorized)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail();
        }
    }
}
```

Add the folder authorization conventions and policies in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Company/Billing", "CanManageCompanyBilling");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Company/Profile", "CanManageCompanyProfile");

            // Change the routing on all pages underneath the Company folder to include the company id in the route.
            options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/Company", model =>
            {
                Regex templatePattern = new Regex("^Company(/|$)");
                foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
                {
                    selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = templatePattern.Replace(selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template, "Company/{company:int}$1");
                }
            });
        });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CanManageCompanyBilling", builder => builder.AddRequirements(new CompanyAuthorizationRequirement("billing")));
        options.AddPolicy("CanManageCompanyProfile", builder => builder.AddRequirements(new CompanyAuthorizationRequirement("profile")));
    });
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a clean way how to this systematically in ASP.NET Core. Since the data binding occurs after the authorization, you have to sniff the `companyId` manually as you do in the part which "smells wrong". [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased) recommends to perform the authorization in the code using custom "resource-based authorization handlers". This is IMHO even worse than the current solution, because it's easier to forget about it (but it makes more sense if you need to load the resource from the DB anyway).